How many minimal graphs on $n$ vertices with radius and diameter of 2 are there?
A simple graph is a minimal graph with radius and diameter of 2 if its radius and diameter are 2, and removing any edge would increase its diameter. The question is how many such unlabelled graphs on $n$ vertices are there.
I was trying to simplify the task by assuming that all such graphs contain a Hamiltonian cycle. But I am not sure if it is true either.
Is it possible to compute in time polynomial on $n$?

Such a graph does not necessarily contain a hamiltonian cycle. For example, consider the graph with 5 vertices (from $0$ to $4$) and 6 edges : $01, 02, 03, 14, 24, 34$.

I see. It looks like the graph would contain a cycle of either $n$ or $n-1$ vertices though...

All complete bipartite graphs $G=(U\cup V, E)$ with $|U| \ge |V| > 1$ have radius $= 2$ and diameter $= 2$. Also, notice that removing any edge would increase the radius and diameter. Thus, it is a minimal graph.
So your required number is at least as large as the number of such complete bipartite graphs having $|U| + |V| = n$. This is an integer partitioning problem with the special constraint $|U| \ge |V| > 1$ and can be easily calculated.

A graph $C_5$ is not a complete bipartite graph.

Also, this integer partitioning is how you count maximal r2d2 graphs: $\sum_{i=2}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}p_i(n-i)$.

@rus9384, You are right; $C_5$ and other graphs can have radius = 2 and diameter = 2. I have updated the answer.
